# How to use Firebase Realtime Database persistence to store some childs of a node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code works fine without any crash but only problem i am having is not able to sync Firebase Realtime Database offline i have tried keepsync(true) on some nodes but doesn't work .I am trying to get reference to a node  Users from Chatlist. What i am trying to do is if a users is logged in he will see the users mentioned under is Uid in Chatlist node inside his recyclerview.I am able to do it successfully but not able to store those users offline when internet connection goes off. It loads all of the users again.

My code

```
    public class Chats extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private UserAdapter mUserAdapter;
    FloatingActionButton profile, credentials;

    DatabaseReference rootRef;
    DatabaseReference ChatlistRef;
    DatabaseReference UserRef0;
    DatabaseReference UserRef1;
    DatabaseReference UserRef2;


    ValueEventListener mValueEventListener;
    ValueEventListener eventListener0;
    ValueEventListener eventListener1;
    ValueEventListener eventListener2;



    List<String>  UserChatList= new ArrayList<>();
    private List<User> mUsers;

    String TAG ="Tag2";
    private static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "Message_Key";

    private Handler mHandler;

    int UserListSize;

    public Chats() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

        //DatabaseReference ChatListReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference
                //("Chatlist").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        //ChatListReference.keepSynced(true);

        profile = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_edit_profile_pic);
        credentials = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_edit_name);
        FabAction();

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        // mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        //callChatlist();
        chatlist_loop();

        return view;
    }

    private void chatlist_loop(){
        mUsers.clear();

        mUserAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers, false);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);
        mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        String fuser;
        fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ChatlistRef = rootRef.child("Chatlist").child(fuser);
        ChatlistRef.keepSynced(true);


        mValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String userID = ds.getKey();

                    DatabaseReference UserRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userID);
                    UserRef.keepSynced(true);
                    Log.d(TAG," UserRef : "+UserRef);


                    ValueEventListener eventListener=new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                            if(!mUsers.contains(user)){
                                mUsers.add(user);
                                mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    };


                    UserRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Log.d(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        };
        ChatlistRef.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be setting persistence anywhere. keepSynced only sets a listener. You need to do something like:

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
bool success = database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

The call to setPersistenceEnabled returns a bool of true if persistence was set.

You need to set persistence before calling your first reference.

Update:

To use Firebase offline you turn persistence on with setPersistenceEnabled(true) when you start the app. After you have done any database calls you cannot turn it off again ie. using setPersistenceEnabled(false) has not effect.

Your existing listeners will ensure the data they refer to stays in sync. If you have database nodes that don't have listeners defined and that you want to keep in sync ie. keep the data fresh, then you use keepSynced to create a listener for them. You can turn that listener on or off using keepSynced(true) and keepSynced(false). If you don't actively keep a specific node data fresh then it is possible the app will use older values from the persisted data on the device as it typically reads that first. However, be careful where you use keepSynced or you could find yourself downloading too much data.

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities for all information.

Comment: So if use this line it will sync all the data  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true); but if i use FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false); and set manually  keepsync(true) it will just sync references which are set to true. or i have to use setEnabled(true) and and manually set false

Comment: See updated answer. If happy with it, please mark as the preferred answer. Thanks.